# Getting response -1 when running woocommerce with node js

Tags: node.js, woocommerce

When I am run the sample of **wc-api-node** I want get the list of products but getting response -1. I given the url and consumer key and consumerSecret.this is git hub link of the project https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-node/blob/master/example.js.

**my code:**

```
var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://www.example.com', // Your store url (required)
  wpAPI: true,
  wpAPIPath: 'wp-rest/', // [optional] the wp rest api path, defaults to 'wp-json/'
  version: 'wc/v1',
  consumerKey: 'ck_**********', 
  consumerSecret: 'cs_*********' // Your API consumer secret (required)
});
console.log("woo commer;"+JSON.stringify(WooCommerce))
// GET example


  WooCommerce.get('products', function(err, data, res) {

  console.log(res)
});
```

Please help me to solve this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameters listed are just examples, you need to set up a wordpress site with the woocommerce plugin installed and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to have an woocommerce and api configured, after this, you need to request the action like this:

```
var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://www.example.com', // Your store url (required)
  consumerKey: 'ck_**********', 
  consumerSecret: 'cs_*********',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v2' // To new version of the Woocommerce Api
  // wpAPIPath: 'wp-rest/', - Removed in the new version of api
});

WooCommerce.getAsync( 'products' ) // this request async data!
  .then( ( result ) => {
    console.log( result );
  } 
);
```

Please tell us if work!